# Changing font size on a list using the CSS Style by entering HTML in Content Editor Webpart

Tags: list

I have a list that that is on a page.  I want the font to be larger just in that list on that particular page in order to print and view the printed version better.  I've found things online that allow increase the font size of the titles on the page, but not the individual items on the list?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Using the content editor web part, or HTML forms web part, you'll want to specify CSS for

```
rows
.ms-vb2, .ms-vb {font-size: 14pt;}

row header
TH .ms-vb {font-size: 14pt; }
```

HTH

Comment: Okay, got it to work for a normal list.  How can I get the list items font size to increase when I have the style of the list view as a Boxed style?  This works for all other views besides boxed?

Comment: Modify .ms-stylelabel and .ms-stylebody.

Answer (score 0):

Most of this font styling is done at the TD level, making it a bit of a pain. Try this definition:

```
.ms-vb,.ms-vb2,.ms-vb-user,.ms-vb a
{
   font-size:15px;
}
```

All three of those 'ms-vb...' classes are attached to TD cells within List Views - in addition, the Title column's font is determined by the styling on the actual Title link (.ms-vb a).

Hope this helps!

EDIT: [image: Dev Tools screenshot]

You can see on the bottom right that .ms-stylelabel has a font-size declaration that applies to the contents of the TD.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was able to use this information and it worked for all views other then a view I have set up as a boxed style.  Any ideas on how to increase the data in a boxed style view?

Comment: Sure -  use .ms-stylelabel,.ms-stylebody { ... }

Label is for the left side, body is for the right.

Comment: thank you.  How did you find that attribute?  I was looking in the HTML and could not find it, even using the locate tool?

Comment: I inspected the row using IE Dev Tools and then tested modifying the style to see if it worked or not -- see post for a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks, that single bit of information on how to find that will help me greatly.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Fant Asy,

You will need SharePoint Designer 2010...

Inside the designer you can edit the data view web parts of Lists and customize how they look, apply CSS and styles...

Here is the simplest formatting in SharePoint Designer 2010:
[SharePoint 2010 List Views – Formatting Tip](http://davepyett.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/sharepoint-2010-list-views-formatting-tip/)

You can also apply [Conditional Formatting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/balsharfi/archive/2011/10/20/sharepoint-lists-conditional-formatting-using-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx) on your List View...

I hope this helps!

Comment: David Lozzi's CSS code is the simplest way to make the change.  I have used the code inside a CEWP on a web page successfully a number of times.  The solution is best for users that do not have access to SharePoint Designer, or do but are not comfortable adding CSS to DVWPs or creating new style sheets.